# Stuck at Syncing files to device Chrome... Flutter Web

Tags: android-studio, google-chrome, flutter, dart, flutter-web

When trying to run my Flutter App on Chrome it loads a blank website and in my console I only get the message;

```
Launching lib\Constants\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Syncing files to device Chrome...
```

There are no errors when I run flutter doctor and I have no problem loading up apps in the emulator.

Comment: Hey Oli, check this out: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54290

Answer (score 1):

Press F12 on Chrome and click on the Console tab to look for errors. Maybe you added something in index.html that is incorrect or there is build errors.

You can also run `flutter build web` to see if there's any errors.

Comment: Flutter build web gives the following error; Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter.

Comment: Run cd nameofyourapp to get to your app.

Comment: There are no errors when running this yet I still have the same problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you even have the pubspec.yaml file in your directory?

Comment: I had moved the punspec.yaml file into a folder which caused that error. However this isn't a problem anymore but the syncing files to device chrome still isn't completing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and solved it with `flutter upgrade` to the newest version.

For Flutter Web & Debug & Chrome:

- Version 1.20.0 stucks
- Version 1.22.0 works fine

Answer (score 0):

A downgrade to Chrome version 84.0.4147.135 solved the issue for me.

https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

Answer (score -3):

I had the same error. Please check, if in Chrome the "Dart Debug extension" is installed.

Look here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dart-debug-extension/eljbmlghnomdjgdjmbdekegdkbabckhm

Then restart your browser. Maybe it works.